# How to start a SWT Plugin test form the command line

Tags: eclipse, testing, swt

I would like to start a SWT plugin test form the command line. I copied the properties from the running thread and I with those arguments eclipse starts but after some time I get:

```
Could not connect to:  : 64268          
     java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
 at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
 at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:351)
 at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:213)
 at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:200)
 at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:432)
 at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)
 at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:478)
 at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:375)
 at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:189)
```

This port is specified as a an command line argument. It seems that some Junit remote runner needs this port. Is there a way to disable this ? I really would like to integrate some automated SWT plugins tests into my Jenkins build.

Regards
  Roger

Comment: I'm using nc to provide the port and it's working. That even allows me to parse the output from the testrunner and look for failed tests.

Comment: Are you using the automated test framework to launch the Junit plugin tests?  That wouldn't need the extra port

Comment: No, I'm using my own. Which framework are you referring to ? SWTBot ?

Comment: I mean the Part 2 of http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-PDE-Automation/automation.html ... there's a way to structure test plugins so that they can be launched and their tests run within the context of a workbench